# Creating a Label for a checkbox inside a repeater

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms, asprepeater

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater1" OnItemDataBound="countryDataBound">
  <HeaderTemplate>        
  </HeaderTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <div class="accordion">
      <span><h3><%# Eval("key") %>
      <div class="panelCountry">
        <input type="checkbox" runat="server" class="chbSelectAll"/><label>SelectAll</label>
        <asp:CheckBoxList 
           ID="chbListCountries" 
           CssClass="chbList"
           RepeatColumns="4" 
           RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
           DataTextField ="Name"
           DataValueField = "CountryCode"
           runat="server">
           <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
         </asp:CheckBoxList>
     </div> 
  </div>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <FooterTemplate>
  </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I have a dialog containing a repeater of all the countries in the world grouped by continent. Each continent is separated by a jquery accordion. Inside each accordion there is a checkboxlist of countries, with a checkbox at the top that functions as a select all. I need to have the label associated with the select all, be responsive. By this i mean if i click the label i need to be able to trigger the checkbox to select all. 
I considered

```
<label for="IDHERE">Select all</label>
```

I cannot however figure out how to correctly target the checkbox so that when i click the specific label it only selects the check boxes in this specific checkboxlist.

Is there anyway to create an ID for each "select all" checkbox that is unique from the other seven so that when the label is clicked on it correclty selects the checkboxes in its respective accordion. 
for reference, when the checbox is clicked this javascript runs:

```
$(document).on('change', '.chbSelectAll', function (e) {
   var selectAllValue = $(this).prop('checked') 
   var panel = $(this).closest('.panelCountry');
   var checkboxes = panel.find('input[type=checkbox]:not(.chbSelectAll)');
   checkboxes.prop('checked',selectAllValue);                             
 });
```

[Visual view of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uImQY.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the `runat=server` tag you can create your own label `for=` by using the ItemIndex.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="chbSelectAll" id="CheckBox_<%# Container.ItemIndex %>" />
<label for="CheckBox_<%# Container.ItemIndex %>">SelectAll</label>
```

But why not use an aspnet CheckBox? Then you won't have that problem anyway.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="SelectAll" CssClass="chbSelectAll" />
```

Comment: I shall try the item index, i actually tried an asp:checkbox. What happens for some reason is the checkbox gets split up into a span containing the checkbox and the label. I couldnt figure out how to then target the checkbox in javascript within this span to then tick all the checkboxes in the list.

Comment: The itemindex worked great thanks :) i have marked this answer as correct! Am still interested in why the asp checkbox breaks up into a span etc but i have work to get on with! thanks for the help

Comment: That is just how aspnet webforms create a checkbox control. You could create your own class to overwrite the default way of creating Controls, but that is much more complicated.

Comment: "i have marked this answer as correct! "

It doesn't look marked correct to me.